# Modifying x labels in normalized grouped stacked bar plots with altair

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

I am trying to create a normalized grouped stacked bar plot using `altair` and was struggling to work with labels. The data is of the format `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` where `A` is the grouping category, `B` is the values of the `x` axis and `C` is the stacking values and `D` is the value. I want to create a graph which looks as follows:

[image: A normalized grouped stacked bar plot with labels but no counts]

There are two objectives I want to achieve with the styling here:

1. Ensure that there's only one `x` label across all the groups called `Type (B)` instead of having it displayed multiple times (`unique(A)` times) below each stacked group.
2. Format the `x` labels in each group to include the value of `N` i.e. replace `Type 1` as `Type 1 (N=20)` AND `Type 2 (N=22)` for `Category 1` etc.., (N values are computed according to the example below)

---

Here's a minimal code sample to reproduce the result of this plot

```
import pandas
import altair as alt


def populate_data():
    data = [
        ['Category 1', 'Type 1', True, 10],
        ['Category 1', 'Type 1', False, 5],
        ['Category 1', 'Type 1', 'V3', 5],
        ['Category 1', 'Type 2', True, 10],
        ['Category 1', 'Type 2', False, 8],
        ['Category 1', 'Type 2', 'V3', 4],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 1', True, 10],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 1', False, 5],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 1', 'V3', 5],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 2', True, 10],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 2', False, 8],
        ['Category 2', 'Type 2', 'V3', 4],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 1', True, 10],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 1', False, 5],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 1', 'V3', 5],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 2', True, 10],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 2', False, 8],
        ['Category 3', 'Type 2', 'V3', 4],
    ]
    header = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=header)
    return df


def plot_grouped_stacked_bars():
    df = populate_data()
    chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('B:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='Type (B)')),
        y=alt.Y('D', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, title='Percentage', format='%'), stack='normalize', sort="-x"),
        column=alt.Column('A:N'),
        color=alt.Color('C:N'),
    )
    chart.save('sample_plot.png')


plot_grouped_stacked_bars()
```

I tried to create a new `altair` layer using `mark_text` by trying to do the following and created a new `alt.layer()` with the `chart` and `text` layers:

```
text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(dx=-15, dy=3, color='black').encode(
        x=alt.X('B:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='Type B')),
        y=alt.Y('D', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, title='Percentage', format='%'), stack='normalize', sort="-x"),
        column=alt.Column('A:N'),
        text=alt.Text('B:N', format=' (N={%d})')
    )
result = alt.layer(chart, text, data=df)
```

but receive an error message `raise ValueError("Faceted charts cannot be layered")`

I feel that my usage of `mark_text()` is incorrect for the grouped stacked bars. An explanation showing how to achieve the results would be very highly appreciated.